# Занесение повторяющихся значений в базу данных postgresql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, запрос

Мне надо вставить данные в базу на postgresql:

```
 INSERT INTO table_subject_topics_exams (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
    VALUES ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number Sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression');
```

Правда,проблема в том, что в данной таблице много повторяющихся записей. В качестве результата я хочу получить пополнение в базе данных ввиде:

```
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'), 
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression');
```

Если там эти данные есть, тогда вообще ничего не вводить.

Как тогда должен выглядеть запрос?

Comment: Вставить, а потом удалить дубликаты. Вероятно будет дешевле, чем проверять каждую запись.

Answer (score 0):

Документация MySQL (синтаксис подобен) говорит, что:

> Используйте команду REPLACE, а не команду INSERT. Если запись новая,
> она вставляется так же, как и INSERT. Если это дубликат, новая запись
> заменяет старую.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть уникальный индекс и postgresql 9.5 или новее:

```
INSERT INTO table_subject_topics_exams (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
select distinct * from (
    values(..),(..)
) s
on conflict do nothing;
```

или

```
INSERT INTO table_subject_topics_exams (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
select * from (
  VALUES (..),(..)
) as s(f1,f2,f3,f4) 
where not exists(
  select from table_subject_topics_exams 
  where name_of_subject = f1 and 
        section = f2 and 
        topic = f3 and 
        subtopic = f4
);
```

Но дубли в передаваемых данных (`VALUES`) лучше бы отсеивать на самом приложении, чем гонять в запросы без нужды.

Answer (score 0):

ИТак,сначала делам поле уникальным

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_table_subject_topics_exams_3 ON table_subject_topics_exams(name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic);
```

А затем начинаем добавлять

```
INSERT INTO table_subject_topics_exams (name_of_subject, section, topic, subtopic)
    VALUES ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number Sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Number sequences'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Arithmetic Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression'),
    ('Algebra', 'Mathematics', 'Progressions', 'Geometric Progression')
    on conflict do nothing;
```